# Java Swing - Draw Station Names using GPS Coordinates on JPanel

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jpanel

I am working on an assignment and got stuck at a certain point.
I am given a `.txt` file with a series of stations, and I am supposed to draw the station names using the GPS coordinates given to me, but I can't translate those coordinates to XY coordinates that a `JPanel` uses. Also, GPS coordinates are written in `double`s but XY coordinates in `int`s.
How can I achieve this?

Here's the code that doesn't work.

```
     void extents() {
 minLong = Double.MAX_VALUE;
 minLat = Double.MAX_VALUE;
 maxLong = -Double.MIN_VALUE;
 maxLat = -Double.MIN_VALUE;

for(Station station : stations){

    if(station.getLatitude()>maxLat){
        maxLat = station.getLongitude();
        maxLong = station.getLongitude();
    }
    if(station.getLatitude()<minLat){
        minLat = station.getLongitude();
        minLong = station.getLongitude();
    }
    if(station.getLongitude()>maxLong){
        maxLong = station.getLongitude();
    }
    if(station.getLongitude()<minLong){
        minLong = station.getLongitude();
    }
}
```

I'm trying to draw them using:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < stations.size(); i++) {

       double scalingFactorx = width/(maxLat - minLat);
double scalingFactory = height/(maxLong - minLong);
double scalingFactor = Math.min(scalingFactorx, scalingFactory);

double drawingX = stations.get(i).getLatitude() * scalingFactor;
double drawingY = stations.get(i).getLongitude() * scalingFactor;
double drawingY2 = height - drawingY; 
gr.drawString(stations.get(i).getName(), (int)drawingX/100, (int)drawingY2/200);
      }
```

I'm getting different coordinates for each station now, however, they are still too close, which means that they didn't get scaled to the `JPanel`.

Thanks!

Comment: what happens when you run the code?

Comment: I don't see anything on the JPanel, because the station names get drawn outside of it.

Comment: Ok, I understand the problem. writing a new answer now.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) The way I'd approach this is to leverage the power of Java-2D. First create a small circle for each point. 2nd add each circle to a single `Area`. 3rd get the bounding box of the entire `Area` (this will be a `Rectangle2D`). 4th create an `AffineTransform` that would scale and move the rectangle so that it is contained within the bounds of the panel` 5th use that transform when drawing the points.

Comment: *"Here's the whole code if it helps"* More than 3 hours before that comment I advised you to post a [mcve]. Are you intending to ignore that advice? I could have grabbed the MCVE, implemented my solution, and posted it back by now. *"I made a pastiebin,"* Don't post code at external links. Instead, [edit] the question!

Comment: I'm sorry for not replying before, I just edited the question with the updated code keeping it to a minimal amount to which can reproduce the error.
I'll make sure that I keep away from external links from now on. :)

Comment: *"updated code keeping it to a minimal amount to which can reproduce the error."* Did you read the link? If so, you apparently misunderstood it. An MCVE / SSCCE is such that we can copy/paste it into an IDE, compile (without a single change) and run it to put the problem onscreen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well,
 Firstly, you should make the minimum and maximum values to be the actual minimums and maximums of the stations:

```
double minLong = Double.MAX_VALUE;
double minLat = Double.MAX_VALUE;
double maxLong = -Double.MIN_VALUE;
double maxLat = -Double.MIN_VALUE;

for(Station station : stations){

    if(station.getLatitude()>maxLat){
        maxLat = station.getLongitude();
        maxLong = station.getLongitude();
    }
    if(station.getLatitude()<minLat){
        minLat = station.getLongitude();
        minLong = station.getLongitude();
    }
    if(station.getLongitude()>maxLong){
        maxLong = station.getLongitude();
    }
    if(station.getLongitude()<minLong){
        minLong = station.getLongitude();
    }
}
```

And then you can do this in your draw method:

```
for (int i = 0; i < stations.size(); i++) {

    double scalingFactorx = width/(maxLat - minLat);
    double scalingFactory = height/(maxLong - minLong);
    double scalingFactor = Math.min(scalingFactorx, scalingFactory);

    double drawingX = (stations.get(i).getLatitude() - minLat)/(maxLat-minLat);
    double drawingY = (stations.get(i).getLongitude() - minLong)/(maxLong-minLong);
    //double drawingY2 = height - drawingY; This line isn't needed. It causes the text to be drawn outside the jpanel.
    gr.drawString(stations.get(i).getName(), (int)drawingX, (int)drawingY);

}
```

Now, what this does is it finds the rightmost and leftmost stations and highest and lowest locations and then scales everything to fit.

Comment: It still draws them outside the JPanel...
The problem  is that the coordinates are in the negative side of the number plane. Example: Yaphank : 40.8256168 : -72.9158461
It only makes sense to draw it outside the JPanel if it's negative. How can I make the center of the JPanel the starting point of the drawing?

Comment: @DavidMisic Oh. I notice another problem. Hand on a second

Comment: https://www.pastiebin.com/590e210b8dce5 Here's my current code, the output looks something like:  Wyandanch : 40.754889 : -73.35781
__________________________________
Scaling factor: 1056.2961854504042
scalingFactorx: 2112.5923709008084
scalingFactory: 1056.2961854504042
drawingX: 430.49233789154636
drawingY2: 390.4378743799776
Station location: 40.754889
Station location: -73.35781
Which indicates that the values are correct but all the station names are so close that it's kind of useless :(

Comment: @DavidMisic You can look into the options of `gr.drawString(...)`. One of them allows you to change fonts. I'll write an example now and edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
   for (int i = 0; i < stations.size(); i++) {

    extents();

    scalingFactorx = width/(maxLat - minLat);
    scalingFactory = height/(maxLong - minLong);
    scalingFactor = Math.min(scalingFactorx, scalingFactory);

    drawingX = (stations.get(i).getLatitude() - minLat)   * scalingFactorx;
    drawingY = (stations.get(i).getLongitude() - minLong)  * scalingFactory;
    drawingY2 = height - drawingY; 
    gr.drawString(stations.get(i).getName(), (int)drawingX, (int)drawingY2);
```

Something like this should fix it.